# Turning a string into an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using PHP with cURL to make requests to an API.

The API responds with an encrypted string which I then have to use `json_decode` on and run it through a pre-defined decrypt method that returns a string.

So I have something like this:

```
echo $response; 
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);

// New instance of Decrypt
$decrypt =  new Decrypt();
$decryptedResponse = $decrypt->decrypt($decodedResponse);
echo $decryptedResponse;
```

Using `var_dump($decryptedResponse)` yields `string(960)` but the string looks like a JSON array.

`{"Title":"Mr","Forenames":"Steve"}`

So what is the best way to rip apart this string so that I can use the variables through an associative array?

I had already tried:

```
foreach(decryptedResponse as $data)
{
    echo $data['Title'];
}
```

But this outputted nothing on the screen.

Am I misinterpreting the use of `json_decode`?

As many have stated it seems you have to decode twice, I'll look into this and share my findings.

Comment: i know nothing of Decrypt, but the string that you dumped looks like a json encoded array. Have you tried `json_decode($decryptedResponse);` ?

Comment: Can't replicate the problem https://3v4l.org/Xj51O

Comment: If the decoded string looks like JSON, have you tried to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
As you told Using `var_dump($decryptedResponse)` yields string(960) but the string looks like a JSON   means your decrypt duration convert it again json. You can try bellow code it may resolve your issue
    $decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);
    // New instance of Decrypt
    $decrypt =  new Decrypt();
    $decryptedResponse = $decrypt->decrypt($decodedResponse);
    $decryptedResponse = json_decode($response, true);
    foreach(decryptedResponse as $data)
    {
        echo $data['Title'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to json_decode again on the decrypt result

```
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);

// New instance of Decrypt
$decrypt =  new Decrypt();
$decryptedResponse = $decrypt->decrypt($decodedResponse);

$decryptedArry = json_decode($decryptedResponse, true);
var_dump($decryptedArry);
echo $decryptedArry['Title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows that the json_decode works like you want it to but it seems like your Decryption class does something weird.

```
$response = '{"Title":"Mr","Forenames":"Steve"}';
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);

var_dump($decodedResponse);
echo $decodedResponse["Title"];
```